# React - Receiving "Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function" in componentDidMount function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving the following error in my `componentDidMount` function of my React component, and am unsure why:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

I've tried binding the `geocode` call but that doesn't seem to help. This also occurs when I call local functions that contain `setState`.

I've bound the `componentDidMount` function in the `constructor`.

Anybody know why this is occuring?

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.initialLoad) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    const pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude,
                    };
                    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    let latlng = pos;
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'latLng': latlng
                    },
                        function (results, status) {
                            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                console.log(results);
                                if (results[1]) {
                                    let addressObject = results[1].address_components;

                                    const cityType = 'locality';
                                    const stateType = 'administrative_area_level_1';

                                    let city = "";
                                    let state = "";

                                    for (let i = 0; i < addressObject.length; i++) {
                                        console.log(addressObject[i]);
                                        if (addressObject[i].types.includes(cityType)) {
                                            city = addressObject[i].long_name;
                                        } else if (addressObject[i].types.includes(stateType)) {
                                            state = addressObject[i].short_name;
                                        }

                                    }

                                    let isCityStateFound = city != "" && state != "";

                                    if (isCityStateFound) {
                                        jQuery('#city-search-ready-status').val('true');
                                    }

                                    let query = isCityStateFound ? city + ', ' + state : EmptyStr;

                                    console.log(query);

                                    jQuery('.tab-panel').find('.input-text input').val(query);

                                    this.setState({
                                        searchValueCity: city,
                                        searchValueState: state
                                    });

                                    this.performProviderSearch();
                                    this.performLocationSearch();
                                } else {
                                    console.log('No results found');
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                            }
                        });
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Binding `componentDidMount` is not necessary since it is called within the correct context to use `this` referencing the component instance. However, all of your callback functions must also have access to the correct `this` in order to work. The callback to `geocoder.geocode` is your issue, and can be corrected by using an arrow function which uses lexical scoping.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow Community!!!

You can easily solve all the problems by using ES6 features.

- Arrow Functions - They have a lexical scoping. So you don't have to bind `this` anymore. [This resource](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881/) compare nicely the differences of functions before & after ES6.
- ES6 Class - By combine the power of arrow functions now you can create methods without bind `this` in the class constructor.

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.initialLoad) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
        };
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        let latlng = pos;
        geocoder.geocode(
          {
            latLng: latlng,
          },
          (results, status) => {
            // Convert this also to an Arrow Function
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              console.log(results);
              if (results[1]) {
                let addressObject = results[1].address_components;

                const cityType = "locality";
                const stateType = "administrative_area_level_1";

                let city = "";
                let state = "";

                for (let i = 0; i < addressObject.length; i++) {
                  console.log(addressObject[i]);
                  if (addressObject[i].types.includes(cityType)) {
                    city = addressObject[i].long_name;
                  } else if (addressObject[i].types.includes(stateType)) {
                    state = addressObject[i].short_name;
                  }
                }

                let isCityStateFound = city != "" && state != "";

                if (isCityStateFound) {
                  jQuery("#city-search-ready-status").val("true");
                }

                let query = isCityStateFound ? city + ", " + state : EmptyStr;

                console.log(query);

                jQuery(".tab-panel").find(".input-text input").val(query);

                this.setState({
                  searchValueCity: city,
                  searchValueState: state,
                });

                this.performProviderSearch();
                this.performLocationSearch();
              } else {
                console.log("No results found");
              }
            } else {
              console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
  }

  performProviderSearch = () => {
    // Do whatever you want here
    this.setState({
      // Update the state
    });
  };

  performLocationSearch = () => {
    // Do whatever you want here
    this.setState({
      // Update the state
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* Your HTML Structure */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note - *Don't manipulate the DOM using jQuery or even using JavaScript. If you do then you're not using the full power of React.*

Let me know if you need further support.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving callback of `geocoder.geocode` to a separate function in component, bind it in constructor, and pass it as a callback.
P.S. Binding of `componentDidMount` is not needed.

Comment: You've identified the problem area, but simply moving the function will not help since the issue is related to scope (at least without explicitly binding the newly created function).